# Sync problems between Lotus Notes 8.5 and iPhone 3G S

Tags: sync, iphone, lotus-notes

The sync process between Lotus Notes 8.5 and iPhone does not work properly.

1. contacts from 'my contacts' folder in Lotus Notes is not sync'ed completely.  There are quite a number of new contact entries I did in Notes, that do not show up in my contacts folder on iPhone 3GS,
2. Message status is not updated between iPhone and Lotus Notes 8.5 client in both directions, i.e. when I reply/work on a message from my iPhone, it does not sync and reflect the proper status in Lotus Notes client 8.5 and vice versa, however, when I work from my Lotus Notes Web client access (through browser access to my mailbox) the sync works perfect in both directions

How can I tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you sync via Traveler?

ad 1) Are your contacts synced correctly between personal address book and the mail file (which exact Notes version are you using)?

ad 2) Pls. contact your admin. Maybe he has to update your Traveler installation on the server or tweak some setting. It's hard to tell without knowing your setup.